# Workflow Management and Jobs Sequencing in Java

Tags: java, frameworks, workflow, jobs, business-process-management

I need to work on a framework where we need to process a sequence of HTTP Requests to different components/services along with some other custom processing in Java as part of a workflow. Users of this framework should be able to integrate/add other similar workflows with a sequence of tasks into this framework. Looking at workflow management open source frameworks available today, it looks like majority of them have been designed for BPM and use BPMN, and some others categorize into Hadoop Jobs Workflow Management. Now my use case is not BPM, neither Hadoop Jobs. Are there simple but efficient frameworks for the same, or should I actually be using BPM frameworks (like Activiti), though my use case is definitely not a BPM use case, but more of a high level process that requires some processing across multiple components across services, in a sequence.